# IronMQ and Laravel linking together

Tags: laravel-5, message-queue, ironmq

I've got a connection to IronMQ from my Laravel 5.1 project. All credentials I have entered in the config are correct and I am able to send messages to Iron. They are visible on the Dashboard they provide.

My question is how do I get those messages back into my Project to be read.

Apparently `Queue::marshal()` is now deprecated. But even still the concept of that feature doesn't make sense to me.

How do I exactly get a message back from Iron and how do I send it to a specific place in my Laravael project?

I currently have a Job Class in place, but no way to execute it.